# how to center position progressbar in java

Tags: java, swing, center, layout-manager, jprogressbar

i want my progressbar at the center of the sreen. i already tried...

```
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

but when i run the program it didnt work. somehow it is not in the middle of the screen. Please help me. See image.

[image]

**HERE ARE MY CODES**

```
public class progressbar extends JFrame {
    private JProgressBar jp;
    private Timer t;
    int i = 0;

public progressbar() {

    setTitle("Loading...");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setVisible(true);
    jp = new JProgressBar();
    // Paint the percent complete on progress bar
    jp.setStringPainted(true);
    jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 30));
    jp.setMinimum(0);
    jp.setMaximum(1000);
    getContentPane().add(jp);
    pack();
    // Create a timer that executes for every 2 millisec
    t = new Timer(2, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            jp.setValue(i++);
            if (i == 1000) {
                t.stop();
                setVisible(false);
                loginInterface l = new loginInterface();
                l.txtUser.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });
    // Start the timer
    t.start();
}
```

The GridBagConstraints

Anchor is Center, Grid Height 1, Grid Width 1, Grid X -1, Grid Y - 1

Comment: already solved the problem. i put the setLocationRelativeTo(null); below the pack(); and it solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create GridBagConstraints and define anchor (among others like x_weight) to center in GridBagLayout

Then add the component to the layout like this

```
    GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints cons = new GridBagConstraints();

//set the constraints properties

layout.addLayoutComponent(JProgressBar, cons);
```

then

```
setLayout(layout)
```

Comment: i already have it. i forgot to post it the Anchor is Center, Grid Height 1, Grid Width 1, Grid X -1, Grid Y - 1.

Comment: You're setting the layout and then not adding the component to the layout as I explained. You need to create an object instead off passing a new one when you set the layout on the JFrame